# Поиск минимального и максимального значения в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть определённая таблица, в ней есть поле "price", тип поля "TEXT".
Нужно найти минимальное и максимальное значение (цену), для этого использую запрос:

```
SELECT MIN(price), MAX(price) 
FROM $table_base
```

Но он возвращает значения: 1 и 999.99 соответственно.
Минимальное значение отрабатывает чётко, а вот максимальное, нет. Так как в столбце присутствуют значения:
1500.3,
1122.22,
13.99,
999.99,
12.12,
79.79,
100.10,
13333.33,
1,
11

Возникает вопрос, как работают данные команды и как решить вопрос с тем что бы они находили верные решения.

Comment: А потом будет спрашивать как проссумировать и найти среднее? Почему бы сразу не объявить поле, содержащее только числа как числовое?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Потому как тогда приходится работать с точкой, а это сложнее и проблематичнее, плюс и занимает больше памяти. После такого чёткого и развернутого ответа уже не нужно спрашивать как суммировать или выполнять иные математические действия. P.S. Мне не нужно суммировать.

Comment: `SELECT MIN(0+price), MAX(0+price) FROM $table_base`

Comment: @Akina не совсем понятно как работает данный запрос, нулём вы приводите строку к числовым значениям? Более развёрнутый ответ, не комментарий, я думаю очень помог бы страждущим и ищущим.

Comment: *нулём вы приводите строку к числовым значениям?* Да. В MySQL это один из штатных методов приведения типа выражения к числовому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда `max()` отрабатывает по тексту, то сортируют числа не в числовом порядке, а по каждому символу, как они идут по алфавиту, поэтому выводит `999.99`, т.к. если смотреть на них с точки зрения текста, цифра 9 идёт позже, чем все остальные по порядку.

Используйте `cast(price as DECIMAL(9,2))` для приведения столбца к числовому, а затем `max()` от этого столбца.

В итоге ваш запрос будет выглядеть как:

```
SELECT MIN(cast(price as DECIMAL(9,2))) as min_price, 
    MAX(cast(price as DECIMAL(9,2))) as max_price
FROM $table_base
```

Пример на [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jDupw4rPSFTg5Rr1cVEkwa/0).